# Function(instance, filename)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-media

I,m working with my first project in Django, And I have a model like that:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    category_name_path = instance.category.category_name
    return f"{category_name_path}/{filename}"


class Gallery(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = ResizedImageField(size=[1920, 1920], upload_to=get_image_path)
    
    def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % (self.category, self.image.url, self.description)
```

It works but I cannot understand how the 'filename' argument is passed to the function? How it works? ;)

Comment: Could you clarify what you're confused about? `filename` is just the second parameter. Are you asking when/where `get_image_path` gets called?

Comment: yes, I'm confused why in this fragment: "upload_to=get_image_path" there is nothing paased to the function, I've expected something like that: "upload_to=get_image_path(x, y)"

Comment: That object will call the function later, potentially multiple times with different inputs. [You can read the documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). You should also look up the term "first-class functions", which is what this paradigm is called where a function can be used as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileField`, which is a superclass of the `ImageField` has a method [**`.generate_filename(…)`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/498195bda492d09ed00d05ab268cad4b8e5c9f21/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L324-L337):

> ```
> def generate_filename(self, instance, filename):
>     if callable(self.upload_to):
>         filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)
>     else:
>         # …
>         pass
>     filename = validate_file_name(filename, allow_relative_path=True)
>     return self.storage.generate_filename(filename)
> ```

This will thus call the parameter. We can also look where the call to `.generate_filename` originates from:

This is by the [**`.save(…)`** method <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/498195bda492d09ed00d05ab268cad4b8e5c9f21/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L91-L99) of the `FieldFile` (not to be confused with `FileField`, `FieldFile` is the file stored in the field):

> ```
> def save(self, name, content, save=True):
>     name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
>     self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
>     setattr(self.instance, self.field.attname, self.name)
>     self._committed = True
>
>     # Save the object because it has changed, unless save is False
>     if save:
>         self.instance.save()
> ```

then this simply originates from the `FileField`'s [**`.pre_save(…)`** method <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/498195bda492d09ed00d05ab268cad4b8e5c9f21/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L313-L318) that calls `.save()` on the `FileField`:

> ```
> def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
>     file = super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
>     if file and not file._committed:
>         # Commit the file to storage prior to saving the model
>         file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
>     return file
> ```

and it thus picks the `.name` of the `FieldFile`.